# why is no allprojects{} in my build.gradle android studio?

Tags: android, paypal, build.gradle

I am working on an android application and I need to add the PayPal payment method to the app so I am using this

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/

but in these steps, I should add this

[Add the SDK to your app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUM2E.png)

The problem is that I can not find allprojects in my build.gradle file and if I add it,it shows me some errors

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATN9Y.png)

this is how my build.gradle file

Any help how to add it to my file, please?

Answer (score 26):

Prior to Android Studio Arctic Fox, the Studio new-project wizard would create a project-level `build.gradle` file that contained an `allprojects` closure:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
  }
}
```

Arctic Fox and higher do not include this. Instead, they use a slightly different system, one that is configured in `settings.gradle`. The default `settings.gradle` in an Arctic Fox project looks like:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
  }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

The `repositories` closure in there serves the same basic role as the `repositories` closure in `allprojects` in the old system. So, add PayPal's `maven {}` content inside of the `repositories` closure in `settings.gradle`.

Answer (score 4):

Check in the Setting Gradle file. this file adds the new functionality to add the dependency resource